# How to put compile time check to execute the code of Unity Components so that a particular line should not execute when its test case are running?

Tags: unity-game-engine, testing, testcase, test-runner

**Requirement:**

I want to put a check on the code so that It should execute only when we are not running test cases.

Comment: Did you check the answer I left?

Answer (score 0):

You can use C#'s [preprocessor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_preprocessor_directives.htm) directives for this.

```
void Start()
{
    #if (!TEST_CASE)
    //Your code
    Debug.Log("test cases");
    #endif
}
```

If you want the code in that `Start` function to execute, define it at the top of the script and before any `using` statement:

```
#define TEST_CASE 

using System;
using UnityEngine;
```

Because `!` is used in the `if` statement, the code in that `if` statement will only execute when `TEST_CASE`  is not defined. Simply comment it out if you need it to execute.